# How to do weighting in regression in SAS?

Tags: sas, regression

I've set up a table with age and average spending by age. Age is my dependent variable. In my dataset, I have a lot of members at age 21, so I need to put more weight on it  when I run regression in SAS. I'm new to SAS. I have used that regression button, but have not written codes. Is there another built in button for weighting? Or how would you do this?

```
Age Ave Spending    Total Members
20  $100              35
21  $80               85
22  $75               20
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify which SAS product you use, but if you use SAS Enterprise Guide, the "Tasks > Regression > Linear Regression" menu gives a "relative weight" option where you can specify Total Members.

[image: Linear Regression Menu]

If you want to do this programatically, here is a short example:

```
DATA regdata;
INPUT Age 3.0
        Ave_spending 3.0
        total_members 3.0;

DATALINES;
20  100 35
21  80  85
22  75  20
;
RUN;


PROC REG DATA=regdata;
    WEIGHT total_members;
    MODEL Age = Ave_spending;
RUN;
```

The "Relative Weight" option translates into the "WEIGHT" command you see in the code above.